# Drupal mulitsite still connects to thesame database

Tags: docker, drupal-7

So I am trying to setup drupal multi site with druap 7.x my apache config looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /d /var/www/html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>


     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /e /var/www/html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I also have the multi site directory setup to ipaddress.d and ipadress.e also note this is inside docker and am forwording port 80 to port 18080 so i can access on my host machine.

I have the settings.php in both site folders and they are pointing to seperate database .

but when i load on the browser both sites still point to same db

Answer (score 0):

Drupal should automatically resolve to the settings file that corresponds to domain/directory name. However if you are having issues ten you can manually resolve using the sites.php file.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/multisite-drupal/set-up-a-multisite#s-step-2-configure-the-first-site-for-the-multisite